# offsetTop return 0

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a function which move a div-Element to the same height as the hovered element.
For this I used offsetTop but it always returns 0 and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            const handle = document.querySelector('#handle');


            const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.et_pb_accordion_item_0, .et_pb_accordion_item_1, .et_pb_accordion_item_2')
                .forEach(el => {
                  el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
                      handle.style.top = `${e.currentTarget.offsetTop}px`;
                });
            });
        });
```

I also tried to use `getBoundingClientRect().top` but it return different values if I scroll dwon

Comment: The position of `e.currentTarget` (what ever element it is) related to its `offsetParent` is `0`, i.e. it is placed at the top of its `offsetParent` element.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for you answer. Is there a way to get the x.position not related to the offsetParent?

Comment: No, but you can set the correct `offsetParent` with CSS. It's complex to explain, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLelement/offsetParent . It's also possible, that you're reading the offset from a wrong element, maybe you need read it from the parent element of `e.currentTarget` ..? An example of the related HTML and CSS would help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use the getBoundingClientRect() as follow:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('elementId');
var offset = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
// you can use
offset.left;
offset.top;
```

**It works for me.**

Comment: this gives the same result of offsetTop to me

Comment: this works? but my question is why does it work?

Answer (score 7):

Calculate the correct `offsetTop` (same solution is valid for `offsetLeft`), recursing all parents until you get null with something like this:

```js
function getOffsetTop(element) {
    return element ? (element.offsetTop + getOffsetTop(element.offsetParent)) : 0;
}
```

Then use that function on your code `getOffsetTop(e.currentTarget)` instead of getting directly `e.currentTarget.offsetTop`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use getBoundingClientRect + window scroll position

I was having the same issue with offsetTop = 0 in some instances, but not others. For that I am still not sure *why*!

I had used `getBoundingClientRect` before with better success, so I adjusted my code to use that approach. As OP said, it gives different numbers depending on how far you have scrolled the window, but we can add that scroll position and get consistent numbers.

```js
let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
let rectViewport = el.getBoundingClientRect();
let top = rectViewport.top + scrollTop;
```

- the `window.pageYOffset` is deprecated but works as a "fallback" in this `||` method.
- the `rectViewport` is our element `el` and utilizing `getBoundingClientRect()`
- the `top` is the combination of the el's viewport top and scroll top

Let's imagine we were scrolled down 200ish pixels, we would see scrollTop to match that. And our element was 2000+ pixels down from the current viewport. We can combine to get 2200+ of the actual window. To see the result, combine with something fun like:

```js
window.scrollTo({
  top: top,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```